# ember-data as data for d3

Tags: ember.js, d3.js, ember-data

I would like to use my emberdata as data for creating objects within d3. I try to convert the items from the controllers model into new javascript objects and giving this new array to d3 data. here is the code

```
App.GraphicsView = Ember.View.extend( {
didInsertElement: function() {
    var svg = d3.select("#svg");
    var data = this.get('controller').get('model').get('content');
    var newData = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          newData.push(data[i]);
     }
    var graphics = svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(newData)
        .enter()
        .append("rect");
    graphics.attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return d.get('x');
    })
}
```

but the data variable ist not realy an array so I cann't iterate over it

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I would like use my data (ember-data) from controller's model in the view for putting it in d3 data. how can I iterate over the data in the controllers model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ember has lots of in-built iterators (Check out the Ember.Enumerable docs). In your case however, simply calling `toArray` should suffice.

```
App.GraphicsView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var svg = d3.select("#svg");
    var data = this.get('controller.content');
    var newData = data.toArray();
    var graphics = svg.selectAll("rect")
      .data(newData)
      .enter()
      .append("rect");
    graphics.attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return d.get('x');
    })
  }
})
```

EDIT:
Here is a working version of your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PkT8x/156/

A couple of things, firstly, you had incompatible versions of Ember and Ember-Data in the fiddle.

Secondly, the `FixtureAdapter` simulates a remote response by default therefore on `didInsertElement` the `App.Graphic` collection was actually empty and it is not until the next runloop that the array was populated with the objects, to fix this, I made Ember re-calculate the d3 object whenever the controller's length changes.

```
App.GraphicsView = Ember.View.extend({
  graphicsObserver: function() {
    var svg = d3.select("#svg");
    var data = this.get('controller.content');
    var newData = data.toArray();
    var graphics = svg.selectAll("rect")
      .data(newData)
      .enter()
      .append("rect");
    graphics.attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return d.get('x');
    })
  }.observes("controller.length")
})
```

Comment: it doesn't work. newData is empty. here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PkT8x/155/

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example : http://jsfiddle.net/2UPLp/16/light/

Requires:

```
d3.v2.min.js
handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js
ember-1.0.pre.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach

https://github.com/sabithpocker/ember-appkit-d3-sample

> This particular method is generating paths with d3 and binding it to
>   the svg using Ember. This will result in paths responding to data
>   changes in the app. The example does not use d3 to render the svg,
>   instead it is using d3 API to calculate the path and use it in svg.